# awk text replacement script

Tags: bash, date, awk

I'm trying to write a script that takes today's date and replaces it with tomorrow's date. My problem relies on the awk command. Here's what I've done so far:

```
date_today=`date`
day_today=`echo $date_today | awk '{print $3}'`
day_tomorrow=$(( ++day_today ))

date_tomorrow=`echo $date_today | awk '{print $3=$day_tomorrow}'`
```

But it doesn't print the expected date. I'm just trying to replace today's date number by tomorrow's date number.

Comment: What about `date -d "$my_date + 1 day"`?

Comment: `awk` is a powerful tool, but that doesn't mean that you've to become so unrealistic that you can't use the right tool for the job. Finish the job with `date` itself.

Comment: OK! thanks for the answers.

Comment: You'll also need to update your Q to show a sample of the date format you are expecting to process. `++dateVal` will sort of work for format like `20180112`, but not at month or year bondaries. Also, did you try searching here for this Q, I know it was asked and answered within the last 10 days. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Since you haven't shown in which format you need to the complete date so I am assuming it could be year-month-date format.

***Solution 1st:*** With `GNU` date in case you have `GNU` date in your system then following may help you on same.

```
date --date="+1 day" +"%Y-%m-%d"
```

***Solution 2nd:*** With a non-GNU date following may help you in same.(Since I have GNU date in my system so I couldn't test it)

```
date -d @$(( $(date +"%s") + 86400)) +"%Y-%m-%d"
```

Also in case you don't need it in above format you could change it by changing `%Y-%m-%d` in above codes.